# Show image with its maximum width only if it doesn't fit the div

Tags: html, css

I'm using Materialize framework and I'm interested in the [Cards](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) component (The small version).

The code goes like: (the `small` class limits the height of the card to `300px`)

```
<div class="card small">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
      <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
      I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a href="#">This is a link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I want to achieve:

- The image must be in the center of its parent
- If the image has a width that's smaller that the cards width, then it should be used with it's full width in the card
- If it's larger than the cards width then it should be cropped to fit the card
- It should be responsive (using `responsive-img` class)

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the image as a `background-image` instead of using the `img` tag?

Comment: @Sanderfish NO, It has to be used as `img`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The image must be in the center of its parent

This can be achieved by applying `margin: 0 auto;` to `.card-image` and setting a max-width that is smaller than the max-width of `.card`.

> If the image has a width that's smaller that the cards width, then it
>   should be used with it's full width in the card

Does this mean the image should not be larger than its original size? If so the demo below should fulfill the criteria. `.card-image` is set to have a max-width of 400px and `.responsive-img` has a width of 350px.

> If it's larger than the cards width then it should be cropped to fit
>   the card

This can be achieved by setting `overflow: hidden;` to `.card-image`.

> It should be responsive (using responsive-img class)

The demo below uses `.responsive-img` on the image. To center the image even when it's cropped, you may set `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` values to `-100%` and `margin` to `auto`. Be sure to set `.card-image` to position relative and `.responsive-img` to absolute.

Here's a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/suefeng/updr2ehp/1/

If you resize the window, the image should crop when the window is narrower. The image is 350x300px.

Answer (score 1):

[Linked a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/zfxe6doe/2/) with examples. Hope this helps.

> If it's larger than the cards width then it should be cropped to fit the card

When you specify the card-small, the height will be constrained. To modify the width, you just need to specify the number of columns to use.

```
<div class="col s6">
```

> If the image has a width that's smaller that the cards width, then it should be used with it's full width in the card

Some images that are too small will be distorted, see the third example with a jpg in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/zfxe6doe/2/).

> It should be responsive (using responsive-img class)

The responsive features baked into Materialize should provide you with some features, for example in second card.

```
<img src="any.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
```